# crontabでcsvに書き込みできない。

Tags: python, python3, cron

初心者です。下記ページを見ながら温度を1分に1回csvに書き込もうとしていますがcronのログに下記のエラーが発生して書き込めていません。

参考:
[室温の変化を見える化する - もみあげあしめ](http://shima-nigoro.hatenablog.jp/entry/2016/10/16/190000)

```
Mar 27 10:56:01 raspberrypi CRON[2995]: (pi) CMD ([2999] python3 /home/pi/record_temp.py >> /home/pi/temperature.csv)

Mar 27 10:56:01 raspberrypi CRON[2995]: (CRON) error (grandchild #2999 failed with exit status 2)

Mar 27 10:56:01 raspberrypi CRON[2995]: (pi) END ([2999] python3 /home/pi/record_temp.py >> /home/pi/temperature.csv)
```

どうすればいいでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

```
import linecache

DEVICE_NAME='28-00000XXXXXXX'

DEVICE_PATH='/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
FILE_NAME='/w1_slave'

class DS18B20:
    def __init__(self):
        self.raw = linecache.getline(DEVICE_PATH + DEVICE_NAME + FILE_NAME,2)[29:]
        self.value = round(float(self.raw) / 1000.0, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DS = DS18B20()
    print("raw value = " + DS.raw)
    print("temperature = " + str(DS.value))
```

```
import time
import datetime
from DS18B20 import DS18B20

print(str(int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()))) + ',' + str(DS18B20().value))
```

```
*/1 * * * * python3 /home/pi/record_temp.py >> /home/pi/temperature.csv
```

Comment: タグから察するに質問者さんは Python 3 をお使いのようですが、参照先は Python 2 を使っています。実際にはどのようなソースコードをお使いなのでしょうか？　ソースコードを適切な形で質問文に含め、質問文だけ見れば自己完結するような形にして頂けると、回答しやすいです。よろしくお願いいたします :)

Comment: [コマンドラインツールを書くなら知っておきたい Bash の 予約済み Exit Code](https://qiita.com/Linda_pp/items/1104d2d9a263b60e104b) によると 2 は「Bash のドキュメントによると）シェルビルトインな機能の誤用」のようですが、[cron が効かない、エラーログの意味](https://teratail.com/questions/124857) に「cron のログでは、エラーがあったことしかわかりません。... などとして、標準出力と標準エラー出力を確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。」とあるので、それを参考に発生したエラーの詳細を調べてみてはどうでしょう？　こんな記事もありますし。[OpenGrok index が cron で動かない](https://chitora.com/blog/?p=759)

Comment: コードを追記しました。温度センサ値をみるプログラムにはコンストラクタを追加しました。室温を出力するプログラムはそのままです。今書いてて気がついたのですが、もしかして室温を出力するプログラムのprint文のstr(DS18B20().value)ここが問題？

Comment: crontabの記載を質問を編集して追記してください。

Comment: crontabの記述を追記しました。

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> * * * * * python /home/pi/record_temp.py >> /home/pi/temperature.csv
> ```

cronの環境変数はどうなっているのでしょうか？ `python`で実行ファイルを見つけられるような設定になっていますでしょうか？
仮にそうだとしても安全のため、実行するコマンドのフルパスを記述すべきです。

Comment: 失礼しました。少し修正しました。
*/1 * * * * python3 /home/pi/record_temp.py >> /home/pi/temperature.csv
この書き方だとフルパスになっていないのでしょうか？

Comment: @geta9374 `python`であれ`python3`であれ、その実行ファイルがどのディレクトリに配置されていて、cronはそこに配置されていることをどのように知るのか、という話です。

Comment: 記述方法に間違いがないのであれば実行ファイルのディレクトリを指しています。

Comment: @geta9374 はい、もちろん記述方法が間違っています。ディレクトリの概念から勉強しなおすことをお勧めします。

Comment: あなたが何を言っているのかわかりません。

Comment: @geta9374 さん、`python3` という書き方はフルパスではありません。これは `PATH` に含まれるパスからの相対パスになっています。もし cron を実行する環境の `PATH` が実験環境のそれと違う場合、cron からは `python3` という書き方で認識できないかもしれません。実際そういうことが良くあるため `python3` 部分をフルパスで書くのはどうかという話になってきます。